# Barcode reader tab then enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to work out a way of making A return function as a tab or vice versa. When the user scans the barcode it moves to the next text field then on the last field it submits the form. Really of sure of this and jquery/ JavaScript to make it happen!

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that your Barcode reader acts like a keyboard, entering some stuff and then a tab? And at the end of the form (i.e. if there are no more form fields) when the Barcode reader issues a "TAB", the form should be submitted?

Comment: When you scan a code it enters the number or letters as if you type them, then it can be set to add a return or tab at the end of the line. The computer sees the scanner as a keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior of barcode scanners is to input the characters followed by "enter." If you meant you want the scanner to move to the next field instead, you can block the enter with something like:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="barcode" id="b1" />
<input type="text" name="otherfield" id="b2" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#b1').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { // barcode scanned!
        $('#b2').focus();
        return false; // block form from being submitted yet
    }
});
</script>
```